# Exist a tool to convert DFM files to sourcecode?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, freepascal

I'm porting a app to FreePasal/Lazarus & found that their form converter is not good. I have a small utility app, and each time I do a change I need to reconvert, relayout and reimport graphics. Plus, some things are messed up.

I wonder if exist a automatic tool for convert the DFM files to delphi sourcecode, so I can do this more easily. Is not problem if the sourcecode is not FPC compatible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The free [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) plug-in has a ["components to code" feature](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?components_to_code.html). Install it in your Delphi IDE and open the form you wish to convert. Select the components and invoke the command, and it will place equivalent creation and initialization code on the clipboard for you to paste wherever you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Updating to trunk versions of both Lazarus (0.9.29) and FPC (2.5.1) might also be a solution.

Several things have changed:

- last month sb started working on the converters (Juha)
- FPC 2.4+ bring the resource handling closer to Delphi (no more .lrs)

Comment: I test that version. Well done! I remove all that lsr nonsense & the form have less errors in rendering.

However, not work read from .dfm on osx, only lfm, but by now is good enough

Comment: There is some JVCL tool to strip properties from dfms (useful when using recent Delphi's DFMs in older versions). I tried cleaning them this way, and linking the .dfms directly in lazarus worked.

Comment: Meanwhile the world has turned a few times more, and a 2.4.2 with a corresponding lazarus that will also fix the OS X is starting it's release candidate cycle